# Does Windows API have a scrollbar control?

Tags: c, delphi, winapi

In Delphi, there is a component called `TScrollBox`, which allows you to add a scrollbar to a `TImage` component.

I need to add a scrollbar to an image in pure Windows API. So does Windows API have such a control? All I found is this [1993 article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997557.aspx)!

If not, then how can I add a scrollbar to my image?

Comment: Does [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) help?

Comment: After you read through the docs and introduction, check out [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298420(v=vs.85).aspx) example. It scrolls bitmap, which may be what you are after.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Windows API provides [two types of scrollbars](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/10/129068.aspx):

One is the standalone [Scroll Bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787529.aspx) control, that comes with its own window handle.

The other is attached to a window that has the `WS_HSCROLL` and/or `WS_VSCROLL` [Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx). The latter is a nonclient scrollbar and not a control. Consequently it doesn't have a window handle. To manipulate a nonclient scrollbar, pass the window handle of the containing window together with the `SB_HORZ` or `SB_VERT` as the *`nBar`* parameter to the appropriate scrollbar functions.

---

Most complete guide to scrollbars (from [The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/)):

- [The scratch program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/23/54576.aspx)
- [Scrollbars, part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/25/54582.aspx)
- [Scrollbars, part 3: Optimizing the paint cycle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/29/54591.aspx)
- [Scrollbars, part 4: Adding a proportional scrollbar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/31/54601.aspx) ([Answer to exercise](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/05/54602.aspx))
- [Keyboard accessibility for scrollbars](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/05/54610.aspx)
- [Scrollbars bart 6 - The wheel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/07/54615.aspx)
- [Scrollbars part 7 - Integrality](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/11/54629.aspx)
- [Scrollbars part 8 - Integral interactive resizing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/13/54639.aspx) ([Answer to exercise](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/15/54647.aspx))
- [Scrollbars part 9 - Maintaining the metaphor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/09/54826.aspx)
- [Scrollbars part 10 - Towards a deeper understanding of the WM_NCCALCSIZE message](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/11/54885.aspx) ([Answers to exercises](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/13/54917.aspx))
- [Scrollbars part 11: Towards an even deeper understanding of the WM_NCCALCSIZE message](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/15/54925.aspx) ([Answers to exercise](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/17/54945.aspx))
- [Scrollbars part 12: Applying WM_NCCALCSIZE to our scrollbar sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/17/54944.aspx)
- [Scrollbars redux: Part 12](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/16/55344.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Win32 defines a scroll bar class, documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787529.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It is weird that Google did not display this result (even in the first 5 pages!) when searching for "winapi Scroll Bar".

Comment: I always include msdn in the search terms and that is enough to help the engines

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Indeed, searching for "winapi Scroll Bar msdn" gave your answer as the second result.