# Print preview window - a smoother approach than displaying on winapi window

Tags: c++, winapi

Some time ago (5 years, I believe), I made print previewer that printed to WMF and when ready, I just displayed it on some window. Naturally with some controls I saw fit and scrollbars. This worked, but was somewhat slow (redrawing could be seen on scrolling or zooming). Lately I see how Firefox displays webpages and scrolls them up and down smoothly, then there's a free pdf viewer SumatraPDF, which also displays PDFs nicely, although it doesn't implement smooth scrolling.

I now look at Direct2D API, and before I dive into it and realize it's not what I wanted to achieve, I'd like to ask **what possible APIs are being used that enable such smooth scrolling**. I know from my NVidia GPU usage monitor that Firefox uses GPU acceleration, but I don't know what's used under the hood. Please offer suggestions.

Comment: Any technique that renders to an off-screen surface can potentially implement smooth scrolling. In fact, the same single rule that applies to flicker-free rendering is the same rule you need to follow for smooth scrolling: During each render pass, each pixel must change its color at most once. Pick any API you see fit (GDI is capable enough to perform fast `BitBlt`s, if you fancy ease of use).

Comment: How are you drawing the WMF? Are you blanking the entire screen on a scroll and drawing everything all over again? If so, that **will** be slow; read Raymond Chen's scrollbar series to learn how to handle scrolling right. Same deal for `WM_PAINT`: use the update rectangle in the `PAINTSTRUCT` to only draw what you need to draw. If you're drawing the WMF with `PlayExMetaFile()` after converting to an EMF with `SetWinMetaFileBits()`, you can pass that rectangle directly in and let Windows take care of the rest.

Comment: [Answer containing links to the entire scrollbar series](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29469939/1889329), originally posted by Raymond Chen on [The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/).

Comment: Er late correction: the rect passed to `PlayEnhMetaFile()` isn't the clipping rect; that function just gets the DC's clipping rect (which IIRC is automatically assigned by `BeginPaint()`). No idea if either `PlayMetaFile()` or `PlayEnhMetaFile()` actually use this for optimizations, though.

Comment: @iinspectable I was using gdi but redrawing whole area on scroll, like andlabs said. I will now study links provided, thanks.