# Nested panel not scrolling as expected. Why not?

Tags: c++, winapi, scroll

I am creating a GUI using C++ and winapi. I have been able to work out a lot of details, but I'm having a bit of trouble with the scrolling of panels within another panel. I know how to do this in c#, but with c++ I am defeated.

[image]

I have created class which generates a panel for a generic "Topic" and I can designate the name of the topic (e.g., "Topic A"). I have create a separate class which generates a Panel to contain all of these topics. That is the TopicHolder. So I pass in a vector with the names as strings. I then generate new Topic objects, each with their own GUI control. I then update the layout of TopicHolder, including all of the Topics, giving them x and y locations based on their standard size.

Everything looks more or less like I want it to initially. If this was c# the topic holder would scroll and the various topics would scroll in and out of sight depending on the exact portion of the larger panel which was visible. In this case, however, scrolling has absolutley no effect. This is my first time working with scrolling on a c++ gui, so I might be missing something.

Below are some of the key code segments. I'd welcome any helpful tips.
Thanks

Adding the topics

```
void TopicHolder::SetTopics(std::vector<std::string> t)
{
  for(unsigned i=0;i<t.size();i++)
  {
    //I give the topic the HWND of the TopicHolder so it can 
    //be properly parented on that GUI element 
    Topic* tmp = new Topic(myHWND, t[i]);
    vectorOfTopics.push_back(tmp);
  }

  UpdateLayout(holderRect);
}
```

Handling topic layout relative to TopicHolder

```
void TopicHolder::UpdateLayout(RECT r)
{
  int buffer = 5;//buffer between elements
  int x = buffer;
  int y = buffer;

  for(unsigned i=0;i<vectorOfTopics.size();i++)
  {
    RECT tmp;
    tmp.left=x;
    tmp.top=y;
    tmp.right = r.right-(2*buffer);
    tmp.bottom = y+Topic::HEIGHT;//standard height per topic
    vectorOfTopics[i].Layout(tmp);
    y+= Topic::HEIGHT+buffer;
  }
}
```

Layout in Topic object

```
 void Topic::Layout(RECT r)
 {
   SetWindowPos(myHWND, //this is the HWND of the topic
     HWND_TOP, r.left, r.top, Topic::WIDTH, Topic::HEIGHT, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
 }
```

-------------------Edit-----------------------------------------

Grr... Okay, so C++ has no support for this as many of you have explained. I have (painfully) been learning to set up my scroll parameters. Mostly it is working as expected, but I still have a problem with the scrollbar. I expected the scrollbar to show up on the right side of the panel and leave the rest of the space for my Topic panels. Instead it is slightly offset and the rest of the area is painted a light gray rather than the background color of the TopicHolder. Right now it's just irritating, but I would like to see it resolved. Again, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In the Windows API, you are responsible for handling all scrolling yourself; there is very little automatic support for scrolling (there's a function that actually moves the pixels of your window and child windows and functions to manipulate scrollbars, but that's it). [Raymond Chen's scrollbar series](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29469939/1889329) is the de facto standard guide on how to do scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Starting `y` position of topics in `UpdateLayout` always remains 5, so no scrolling happens. You should keep some offset value and change it if scrolling up and down happens so `y` will start from this offset.

Comment: Sorry that is not correct. The y value is updated at the end of the loop so that the line advances for each Topic added. It is possible that I could change the initial position to enforce scrolling and if I did that I may as well not have the scroll bar. What I want is a scroll bar that causes this motion to happen automatically.

Comment: I tested your solution and it works. By setting up a variable to track my intended scroll, I can change the position of the Topic panels. Still, I want to have the scroll bar do this automatically. I get that sort of behavior from the ListView where I select the various topics, but this panel is not working as expected.

Comment: ListView is doing that itself. If you want that functionality in your own custom class, you will have to do so yourself too. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `SetScrollPos()` to change the scrolling position or the window contents.

i.e:

```
// hwnd is your control window, SB_VERT refers to its verti8cal scrollbar.
SetScrollPos(hwnd, SB_VERT, topicHeight * topicToBringToTop, TRUE);

InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);   // redraw the control.
```

Comment: Hmm. First, this is setting the scroll position programatically and I want it to adjust normally with the GUI. Even so, I tried it and had very odd results. The GUI isn't changing. I ran SetScrollPos for two different values and per the documentation I saw it return 0 (the initial position) and then the first value I set it to. So it is being set, but I'm not seeing any change in the topics or in the scrollbar. sorry.

Comment: @BSD if your control is not a list box.  you will have to keep track of the scroll position by capturing scroll messages and take that into account in your WM_PAINT.  Since your control is a list, using a custom draw list would have avoided this kind of issues from the start.